# Syntax error in PHP using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to `PHP` and learning it with `Codeigniter`, While following a tutorial i get:

> **Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected '⇒' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\stud\application\views\Stud_edit.php on line 16

while my `Stud_edit.php` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang = "en">

   <head> 
      <meta charset = "utf-8"> 
      <title>Students Example</title> 
   </head> 

   <body> 
      <form method = "" action = "post">

         <?php 
            echo form_open('Stud_controller/update_student'); 
            echo form_hidden('old_roll_no',$old_roll_no); 
            echo form_label('Roll No.'); 
            echo form_input(array('id'⇒'roll_no', 'name'⇒'roll_no','value'⇒$records[0]→roll_no)); 
            echo "
            "; 

            echo form_label('Name'); 
            echo form_input(array('id'⇒'name','name'⇒'name',
               'value'⇒$records[0]→name)); 
            echo "
            "; 

            echo form_submit(array('id'⇒'sub mit','value'⇒'Edit')); 
            echo form_close();
         ?> 

      </form> 
   </body>

</html>
```

Can anybody please make out what's the mistake here?

Comment: Here is `$records[0]→roll_no`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you have copy paste this from somewhere. There is special characters(⇒ and →) in your code which is not allowed

Change

`echo form_input(array('id'⇒'roll_no', 'name'⇒'roll_no','value'⇒$records[0]→roll_no))`;

To

```
echo form_input(array('id'=>'roll_no', 'name'=>'roll_no','value'=>$records[0]->roll_no));
```

Comment: Yes. That solved my problem. Thank you :)